# Matrix column as AND operation

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

My array is

```
[[1. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [6. 7. 6. 2. 2.]]
```

I want to take zero row and first row to do "AND" operation and count total
like this:

```
[[1. 1.] 1
 [0. 1.] 0
 [0. 1.] 0
 [1. 1.] 1
 [1. 0.] 0
 [0. 1.] 0
 [1. 0.] 0
 [1. 1.] 1
 [1. 1.]] 1
```

but I want to zero row and second row , zero row and third row ,zero row and four row , first row and second row , first row and third row....keep going
like this :

```
 row[0]row[1] , row[0]row[2] , row[0]row[3] , row[0]row[4]
 row[1]row[2] , row[1]row[3] , row[1]row[4]
 row[2]row[3] , row[2]row[4]
 row[3]row[4]
```

I take the zero row and second row code:

```
q = []
first = [int(row[0] and row[1])for row in array[:-1]]
c = sum(first)
q.append(c)
print(c)
```

How can I do?
I use Python3 and Numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[int(m[k][i] and m[k][j])
  for k in range(len(m))
 ] for i, j in combinations(range(len(m[0])), 2)]
```

If you also want to see which columns were ANDed for each subresult:

```
{(i, j): [int(m[k][i] and m[k][j])
  for k in range(len(m))
 ] for i, j in combinations(range(len(m[0])), 2)}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want all the combinations of the columns, you can use `itertools.combinations()` to get the combinations and a couple of `zip()` calls to get what you want:

```
In []:
[[int(all(r)) for r in zip(*p)] for p in it.combinations(zip(*a[:-1]), r=2)]

Out[]:
[[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Or if you need to transpose the results into columns:

```
In []:
list(zip(*[[int(all(r)) for r in zip(*p)] for p in it.combinations(zip(*a[:-1]), r=2)]))

Out[]:
[(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
 (1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)]
```